# R shiny special characters

Tags: r, shiny

I'm developing an application in R shiny. I'm reading SAS XPT files using `read.xport` function and creating data tables. I use Labels of the data table columns to display choices in a `checkboxGroupInput`. It works well for all SAS datasets but few(I get the error : `string 1 is invalid in this locale`) and when I researched I found out that some of the column labels have special characters, for example here is a column(label) `CNTRYLNM(Country, Long Name�)`

When I display the label with `unname(label(datatable))`, it comes as `"Country, Long Name\xa0"` other column labels have \xa1 at the end.

How do I get rid of these while reading from xpt itself or afterwards?

Comment: You can do something like `iconv("Country, Long Name\xa0", to='ASCII', sub='')` to remove the special characters.

Comment: It may work as a work-around, is there a way to convert them to ASCII while reading the sas xpt file itself?